# How to fetch data from another server using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to fetch the data from one of my files located at different url.Here is the code that shows the ajax request sent to the server

```
<script>
    alert('return sent');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "example.com/show.php",
        data: 1
    })
    success: function data(response) {
        alert(data); // apple
    }
</script>
```

Here is the code on another file  that I am accessing through Ajax (example.com/show.php).

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello '; 
?>
```

However I am getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked:  warning in my console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: i want to achieve it without Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replce your show.php like

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *");
echo 'Hello ';

?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Is this safe to use?

Answer (score 1):

add in show.php

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, *");
```

Comment: You are also correct first saw that one so accepted it.